# How to Customize background color from Tabs using Angular 2+ directives?

Tags: css, background, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I'm trying to set different backgrounds for each one of my tab labels that are inside a 'md-tab-group' as follows:

```
`<md-tab-group class="full-width">
      <md-tab>
        <ng-template md-tab-label>
            <md-icon class="em-tab-icons">directions_boat</md-icon>
        </ng-template>
        <p>Slings</p>
     </md-tab>

     <md-tab>
        <ng-template md-tab-label>
            <md-icon class="em-tab-icons">local_gas_station</md-icon>
        </ng-template>

        <p>Fuels</p>
     </md-tab>

     <md-tab>
        <ng-template md-tab-label>
            <md-icon class="em-tab-icons">restaurant_menu</md-icon>
        </ng-template>
        <p>Consumables</p>
    </md-tab>
</md-tab-group>`
```

As i know that 'md-tab-label' is a directive than i know that i can not set an 'id' or set a class to override some attributes.

I inspected the classes used by Material Design and i found the class 'mat-tab-labels'.
So, i tried to do this on my scss:

```
` .mat-tab-labels:first-child {
    background-color: #E1E8F5;
  }
  .mat-tab-labels:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: #FFD9B9;
  }
  .mat-tab-labels:nth-child(3) {
    background-color: #E6D2C8;
  }`
```

but it didn't work. Of course that if i use something like this:

```
` #md-tab-label-0-0{
    background-color: #E1E8F5 !important;
  }
  #md-tab-label-0-1{
    background-color: #FFD9B9 !important;
  }
  #md-tab-label-0-2{
    background-color: #E6D2C8 !important;
  }`
```

and it works, but only the first time i enter the page, than the ids change.

So, any ideas ? Do i have to create a Directive only for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your .scss is targeting the parent container div `.mat-tab-labels`, which probably doesn't have multiple nodes. What I think you need to be targeting are each `.mat-tab-label` node within that parent container.

If you update your .scss file to have the following then your conditional colors should work:

```
`
  .mat-tab-label:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: #E1E8F5;
  }
  .mat-tab-label:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: #FFD9B9;
  }
  .mat-tab-label:nth-child(3) {
    background-color: #E6D2C8;
  }
`
```

Comment: Perfect @Gumz ! It works like a charm! Sometimes it's hard to understand what a directive does with html, like the md-tab-labels. I didn't know that when i go within .mat-tab-label:nth-child(n), i would be selecting siblings, instead of children. Thank you again!